# How to get selected word index in Textbox in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I am trying to get the index of selected word on mouse click from the textbox using jQuery.

I should get an index of the word on click like this:

```
WIFI -> 0
, -> 1
Parking -> 2
Available -> 3
! -> 4 
! -> 5
Internet -> 6
Includes -> 7
? -> 8 
? -> 9 
. -> 10 
IS -> 11 
Internet -> 12 
Working -> 13
```

So on selection of Internet it should return me 12 as index position.

Currently I am using the using the following approach, but using this approach I am getting only the selected word's character position.

```
$("#idTable1 > tbody > tr").on('click', function (e) 
{
var start = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionStart;
var end = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionEnd;
```

But on click of the word I should get the index of the tokenized word in the sentence.

Any pointers would be helpful to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're farming downvotes because your question likely does not meet the guidelines. Please review them and fix your question.

Comment: This would be really easy if the sample input used proper grammar. You could remove all characters except a-z, then split into an array using a space as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the string in the textbox by " " and then using `var start = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionStart;` calculate which element of your array contains the word you are looking for...

```
var arr = Split(document.getElementById("inputTxt").value, " ");
var start = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionStart;
var arrpos = 0;
var idx = 0;
for(idx=0; arrpos<start & idx < arr.lenght; idx++){
    arrpos += arr[idx].lenght;
}
return idx;
```